# Object is null since the second method call

Tags: java, android, reference, variable-assignment

With the following code, the script enters in the block of `if (mySet! = null)` only at the first call of the method.

**Why since the second call `mySet` results as `null`?**

```
Map<Integer, Set<String, String>> mMap;

// ... code to populate the map with correct elements

public String myMethod(int idName)
{
    String html = "";

    Set<String> mySet = mMap.get(idName);
    // Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>(mMap.get(idName));
    if(mySet != null)
    {
        // the script enters here only at first call?!?!?

        for(String name : mySet)
        {
            html += ", " + name;
        }
        mySet.clear();
    }

    return html;
}

myMethod(1); // return some html
myMethod(1); // return empty html...
```

If i replace this line:

```
Set<String> mySet = mMap.get(idName);
```

with this line:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>(mMap.get(idName));
```

it works at every call.

The `map` elements are correctly setted, each call is made without changing activity and without rotating the device and making no other possible action.

Comment: Where do you initialize `mMap`?

Comment: You clear the set though. It's immutable, but anything you do on the reference still affects the map. Remove the clear call

Comment: @MuratKaragöz outside the method, before call it for the first time.

Comment: `mySet.clear();` clears the set after first method call, on second call since its empty, it returns empty html.

Comment: @user2342558 yes, I updated. If you want  to retain the set value, you don't need to clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>(mMap.get(idName));
```

creates a new set that is a **copy** of the content that you have in your map. If you instead directly work on the set object stored in the map, you update the "map" content as well.

That is all there is to this: the difference between modifying your "root" data map, versus updating a **copy** of that data.

Answer (score 1):

As Set is the Reference type object, so for the first time when it matches the condition and then clears the set, so now the set becomes empty and so the value corresponding to `1` becomes `[]` empty set.
Suppose myMap has value:
   `1, ["1", "2", "3"]`

Now when you execute `myMethod(1)` for the first time it clears the set corresponding to the value of `1`

Now the map value becomes:
   `1, []`

So it again satisfies your condition  `if(mySet != null)` but it doesn't adds anything to `html` variable as the set `mySet` is empty. So, it return the empty html variable.

Comment: Since the second call, it *does not* evaluate as `true` the `if(mySet != null)` expression.

Comment: In the second call as your set is empty [] but not null( [] != null gives true), so it goes inside the if condition but in your for loop, you are accessing for(String name : mySet) as mySet is empty it doesn't adds anything to the html variable and it return the empty html variable

Comment: from the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) it says that the `get` method of `Map` will return `null` if the key isn't in the map. Please, explain more to me.

Comment: In the scenario mentioned in the question you are not removing the key of the hashmap, but you are accessing the value of a particular key and clearing the value of the particular set to [], still the key exists in the existing map, So when your are calling the method again the map still have the key `1`, so it gives the value corresponding to `1` i.e. [], which is not equal to null, so now your value from the hashmap is empty i.e [], so the if condition is satisfied.

Comment: I understand it, thansk +1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix that by **clone mymap.get(idName) to myset**

```
    public String myMethod(int idName)
{
    String html = "";

    Set<String> mySet = (Set<String>) ((HashSet<String>) mymap(idName)).clone();

    if(mySet != null)
    {
        // the script enters here only at first call?!?!?

        for(String name : mySet)
        {
            html += ", " + name;
        }
        mySet.clear();
    }

    return html;
}
```

Comment: `change mySet variable as HashSet` I think isn't helpful, instead doing so will make the code less maintenably because maintaing it as Set I'll can change the implementation class if needed, without change the variable type.

Comment: Why should I cast twice the map?

Comment: Also, I don't need to clone the whole map but to put in the Set only the Set tied to the key passed in the method.